# Changing axis formatting in kendo stock chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dataviz

Think that I have a chart as you can see in the following url:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/financial/index

I want to change the floating digits of axis that I marked with [red rectangle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwv_-8Q17wGaMnZkSVUtUUFkeHc/edit?usp=sharing).
What setting do I have to edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can change the template of label using the following setting:

```
valueAxis: {
    //majorUnit: 0.2,
    labels: {
      template: "#=  kendo.toString(value, '0,.0;(0,.0)') #" + "%"
    }
  }
```

Here is the [full sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/@tsvetomir/igAK).